# My institution requires publication in Clarivate-indexed journals - what should I do if paper is accepted by a journal at risk of being de-indexed?

Tags: journals, bibliometrics, evaluation-criteria

My department requires that papers are published in a journal that has an impact factor and is indexed in Web of Science.

I submitted a paper to one of these and went through four rounds of review, and now my paper is accepted. However, the journal is now considered "On Hold" by [Clarivate](https://mjl.clarivate.com/journal-profile) and is at risk of being removed from their indices:

> On Hold

> Concerns have been raised about the quality of the content published in this journal. The journal is being re-evaluated according to our selection criteria; new content will not be indexed during the course of the re-evaluation.

> When the evaluation is complete, the publisher will be informed of the outcome and the journal will either:
> be removed from coverage if it no longer meets the quality criteria
> or remain covered if it continues to meet the quality criteria.
> If the journal meets the quality criteria, any missing content will be indexed. If the journal is removed from coverage, content will not be backfilled. In the most serious cases of breaches in a journal's editorial standards, as determined by our selection criteria, published content may be removed from Web of Science. Timeframes for completing a re-evaluation will depend on the particular circumstances of each case.

Will this status "on hold" affect the impact factor for the journal (it is Q1 currently), and how long it will be "on hold"? What should I do with my paper?

Comment: Can you explain why you care what "clarivate.com" thinks about this journal? They are a for-profit multi-billion-dollar corporation...

Comment: You haven't named the journal, nor its publisher. It would be a problem if the journal is predatory.

Comment: Predatory journals will publish just about anything if you pay their fees. They are not reputable or reliable. [Bealle's List](https://scholarlyoa.com/publishers/) may be too old to completely rely on, but it is a place to start. Sharing the name of the journal here shouldn't cause any problems.

Comment: The only people who can tell you how that would be interpreted in context of your departmental regulations live in your department.  Talk with your chair about it.

Comment: If the journal is in the first quartile (Q1) then it is unlikely to be de-classified *for academic reasons*.  Clarivate may be trying to pry some concessions from the publisher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I read this right, then you published in Journal of X for which later on Clarivate and their indexing products decided that they don't trust Journal of X any more. There is nothing you can do about this: The dispute is between Journal of X and Clarivate, and you are not party of the dispute; you are just an innocent bystander.

If your department requires you to publish in journals that are indexed by Clarivate, then the truth is that you are likely out of luck. You can't *force* Clarivate to index (or continue to index) Journal of X. You can of course discuss with your department head whether they still accept your publication for their purposes, and maybe they will if you explain that at the time you submitted the publication, the Journal of X was still indexed.

Going forward, you will want to make sure that (i) you keep doing good work by international standards, and (ii) choose journals to publish in that are of high quality and high ethical standards, and consequently will continue to be indexed in the future.

Comment: Actually, I read it that the article was accepted, not published. There may be something that can be done.

Comment: what is the expected time that I should know the result of the re-evaluation process, please?

Comment: Does this evaluation mean that the journal isn't good or will be removed? or it is just a routine procedure

Comment: @user20133451 The status text which you included in your question states: "Concerns have been raised about the quality of the content published in this journal" - why would you think they mean anything different than what they've said directly?

Comment: cause there is a probability for "remain covered if it continues to meet the quality criteria" as the status text included so i'm asking for what is the expected time for the re-evaluation process and does that a routine procedure for some journals in this duration

Comment: The time frame is also covered in the text you quote: "Timeframes for completing a re-evaluation will depend on the particular circumstances of each case." In other words, it is what it is. There is nothing you can do but wait.

Comment: And yes, in all likelihood the journal you choose isn't any good.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth - that is a little unfair, since (1) their advisor may have had a hand in the selection, and (2) it was indexed before, so met the criteria. Only in retrospect might it be a bad move.

Comment: @JonCuster I didn't say the choice was bad. I said that the journal was bad.